# How would I display an error message when an incorrect file extension/format has been selected from FileDialog in SWT Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, messagebox

I would like to add an error message if the incorrect file format has been uploaded to the text field on button click. I have an error message working for when the textfield is empty. Can anyone suggest anything for this? Any documentation that would be worth looking at for this particular problem? Any help would be appreciated.

```
btnRun.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                        switch(e.type) {

                        case SWT.Selection:
                            if(txtFile.getText() == null || txtFile.getText().isEmpty()) {
                                MessageBox error = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ERROR_UNSPECIFIED | SWT.OK);
                                error.setText("Empty txtFile");

                                // open dialog and await user selection.
                                error.open();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Also note that `SWT.ERROR_UNSPECIFIED` is **not** a valid style for `MessageBox`

Comment: @greg-449 yes I have. As I said in my question I have used a messagebox to display general information somewhere else in my code and it works there but not in this error example.

Comment: @greg-449 I was missing a bracket. I have it fixed now! Thanks for your help with this issue! I have edited my question. Do you know of a way (or any documentation) to only allow certain file types to be used?